# No scientific y-axis matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am getting a scientific notation y-axes label with this code. I just want plain numbers. How do I do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
#display(HTML("<style>.container { width:70% !important; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FormatStrFormatter

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [20, 10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.semilogy(df.close)
ax.grid()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: `set_minor_formatter` ?

Comment: That comment helped. I set both ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f')) and it works. This is the last thing you do before plotting or it gets overriden.

Comment: You need to set the formatters *after* setting the scale. The order of other things doesn't matter. (In this case `ax.semilogy` implicitely sets the scale, so `.set_..._formatter` needs to come after `ax.semilogy`)